# Remove a row from MySQL table and modify a specific field

Tags: mysql

In this table

```
mysql> select * from classics;
+--------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------+------+-------+---------------+
| author                   | title                        | category        | year | pages | isbn          |
+--------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------+------+-------+---------------+
| Mark Twain (S.L.Clemens) | the adventures of tom sawyer | Classic Fiction | 1876 | 65535 |               |
| Charles Dickens          | A Christmas Carol            | Classic Fiction | 1849 |    50 | 23423664      |
| NULL                     | NULL                         | NULL            | NULL |  NULL | 23242362346   |
+--------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------+------+-------+---------------+
```

How do I remove the last row and set the isbn number of the first row?
I'm trying something like this:

```
alter table classics drop ?? where author=NULL;
insert into classics(isbn) values('234525246') where title like "%adventures%";
```

How to do this correctly?

Comment: what if you have two consecutive authors that have `NULL` isbn? where will the value of the last isbn be inserted?

Comment: consider using `NULL` and `ISNULL` MySQL functions.

Comment: @TMOTTM: I did not downvote. But my guess is that it is because you are asking a very fundamential question. You should really read about SQL before using it.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 statements for that. To delete a row use `delete`

```
delete from classics 
where author IS NULL;
```

To update a value in an existing row use `update`

```
update classics 
set isbn = '234525246'
where title like '%adventures%';
```

`alter` is used to change the structure of a table and not its content.
`insert` is used to insert new data into a table and not to modify existing one.

Comment: @TMOTTM: Or use `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`. Comparing something to  `NULL` will always result in `unknown`. That is why you have to use the  `IS` operator for `NULL` comparison.